# Need help on a problemset in a programming contest

Tags: algorithm

I've attended a local programming contest on my country. The name of the contest is "ACM-ICPC Indonesia National Contest 2013".
The contest has ended on 2013-10-13 15:00:00 (GMT +7) and I am still curious about one of the problems.
You can find the original version of the problem [here](http://john.petra.ac.id/~m26410038/INC-2013-C.htm).

**Brief Problem Explanation:**
There are a set of "jobs" (tasks) that should be performed on several "servers" (computers).
Each job should be executed strictly from start time S<sub>i</sub> to end time E<sub>i</sub>
Each server can only perform one task at a time.
(The complicated thing goes here) It takes some time for a server to switch from one job to another.
If a server finishes job J<sub>x</sub>, then to start job J<sub>y</sub> it will need an intermission time T<sub>x,y</sub> after job J<sub>x</sub> completes. This is the time required by the server to clean up job J<sub>x</sub> and load job J<sub>y</sub>.
In other word, job J<sub>y</sub> can be run after job J<sub>x</sub> if and only if E<sub>x</sub> + T<sub>x,y</sub> ≤ S<sub>y</sub>.

The problem is to compute the minimum number of servers needed to do all jobs.

**Example:**
For example, let there be 3 jobs

```
S(1) =  3 and E(1) =  6
S(2) = 10 and E(2) = 15
S(3) = 16 and E(3) = 20
T(1,2) = 2,  T(1,3) = 5
T(2,1) = 0,  T(2,3) = 3
T(3,1) = 0,  T(3,2) = 0
```

In this example, we need 2 servers:

```
Server 1: J(1), J(2)
Server 2: J(3)
```

**Sample Input:**
*Short explanation:* The first `3` is the number of test cases, following by number of jobs (the second `3` means that there are 3 jobs for case 1), then followed by E<sub>i</sub> and S<sub>i</sub>, then the T matrix (sized equal with number of jobs).

```
3
3
3 6
10 15
16 20
0 2 5
0 0 3
0 0 0
4
8 10
4 7
12 15
1 4
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
4
8 10
4 7
12 15
1 4
0 50 50 50
50 0 50 50
50 50 0 50
50 50 50 0
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Case #1: 2
Case #2: 1
Case #3: 4
```

**Personal Comments:**
The time required can be represented as a graph matrix, so I'm supposing this as a *directed acyclic graph problem*.
Methods I tried so far is brute force and greedy, but got Wrong Answer. (Unfortunately I don't have my code anymore)
Could probably solved by dynamic programming too, but I'm not sure.
I really have no clear idea on how to solve this problem.
So a simple hint or insight will be very helpful to me.

Comment: I am relatively new to Stack Overflow. I want to ask if this kind of question is inappropriate or considered off-topic.

Comment: Have you tried modeling this as a max-flow-min-cost problem? - I believe that's the way to go.

Comment: @Skeen, thank you for the insight, I haven't tried it before..

Comment: @topher: The general idea is that you want to produce a model, where all jobs are taken care of (the flow), while minimizing the number of servers required to do this (the cost).

Comment: @ivy - no this question is not suitable for Programmers. All you have done is create work for the mods to clean up the cross site duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by computing the [maximum matching in a bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs).

The idea is you are trying to match job end times with job start times.

A matched end time x with start time y means that the same server will do job x and job y.

The number of servers you need will correspond to the number of unmatched start times (because each of these jobs will require a new server).

Example Python code using NetworkX:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.DiGraph()

S=[3,10,16] # start times
E=[6,15,20] # end times
T = [ [0, 2, 5],
      [0, 0, 3],
      [0, 0, 0] ] # T[x][y]
N=len(S)

for jobx in range(N):
    G.add_edge('start','end'+str(jobx),capacity=1)
    G.add_edge('start'+str(jobx),'end',capacity=1)
    for joby in range(N):
        if E[jobx]+T[jobx][joby] <= S[joby]:
            G.add_edge('end'+str(jobx),'start'+str(joby),capacity=1)

print N-nx.max_flow(G,'start','end')
```